# How can I send input parameter data to a report on a dashboard in Splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am using Splunk to create a dashboard.  I added a report to the dashboard that returns all of the data from the search into a table. I want to add a few input fields so the user to option to filter the data of the report.  The first input is a textbox field.  The default and initial values are set to with an *.  That I hope means everything.
This is the xml created from the dashboard:

```
<form>
  <label>Thru Train Dashboard</label>
  <fieldset submitButton="false" autoRun="true">
    <input type="text" token="purchCostReferenceToken" searchWhenChanged="true">
      <label>TMS Reference Number</label>
      <default>*</default>
      <initialValue>*</initialValue>
    </input>
  </fieldset>
  <row>
    <panel>
      <title>Thru Train XML DATA</title>
      <table>
        <search ref="ThruTrainReportNestedResults"></search>
        <option name="drilldown">row</option>
        <option name="rowNumbers">true</option>
      </table>
    </panel>
  </row>
</form>
```

I know I have to use the token value **purchCostReferenceToken** as an input to the report **ThruTrainReportNestedResults**.  But not sure how to do that since the report search as no input parameters.

This is the search query that creates the report, **ThruTrainReportNestedResults**

```
 sourcetype... | xmlkv | rex max_match=0 "\<purchasedCostTripSegment\>(?P<segment>[^\<]+)" |eval Segments =  mvrange(1,mvcount(mvindex(segment, 0, 2))+1,1) | rex max_match=0 "\<carrier\>(?P<Carriers>[^\<]+)" | rex max_match=0 "\<billingMethod\>(?P<BillingMethod>[^\<]+)" | rex max_match=0 "<purchasedCostTripSegment>[\s\S]*?<origin>\s*<ns2:numberCode>(?P<Origin>\d+)"  | rex max_match=0 "<purchasedCostTripSegment>[\s\S]*?<destination>\s*<ns2:numberCode>(?P<Destination>\d+)" | rex max_match=0 "<purchasedCostTripSegment>[\s\S]*?<stopOff>\s*<ns2:stopOffLocation>\s*<ns2:numberCode>(?P<StopOffLocation>\d+)" | eval Time =_time | convert timeformat="%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S" ctime(Time) | table purchCostReference, eventType, Time, Segments, Carriers, BillingMethod, Origin, Destination, StopOffLocation | sort Time
```

Is there a way to filter the results of this query from a dashboard using input data?  The input data that I would want to filter on would be the purchCostReference, eventType, and Segments

**UPDATE**
I removed the reference to the report and added the search string that creates the report but am getting the error **Invalid character in tag name**.  The search string is very long...

```
<row>
    <panel>
      <title>Thru Train XML DATA</title>
      <table>
        <search base="baseSearch">
             <query>
                index... sourcetype="..." "<billingMethod>RULE</billingMethod>" "createMessage MsgSource" | xmlkv | rex max_match=0 "\<purchasedCostTripSegment\>(?P<segment>[^\<]+)" |eval Segments =  mvrange(1,mvcount(mvindex(segment, 0, 2))+1,1) | rex max_match=0 "\<carrier\>(?P<Carriers>[^\<]+)" | rex max_match=0 "\<billingMethod\>(?P<BillingMethod>[^\<]+)" | rex max_match=0 "<purchasedCostTripSegment>[\s\S]*?<origin>\s*<ns2:numberCode>(?P<Origin>\d+)"  | rex max_match=0 "<purchasedCostTripSegment>[\s\S]*?<destination>\s*<ns2:numberCode>(?P<Destination>\d+)" | rex max_match=0 "<purchasedCostTripSegment>[\s\S]*?<stopOff>\s*<ns2:stopOffLocation>\s*<ns2:numberCode>(?P<StopOffLocation>\d+)" | eval Time =_time | convert timeformat="%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S" ctime(Time) | table purchCostReference, eventType, Time, Segments, Carriers, BillingMethod, Origin, Destination, StopOffLocation | sort Time
            </query>
        </search>
        <option name="drilldown">row</option>
        <option name="rowNumbers">true</option>
      </table>
    </panel>
  </row>
```

**UPDATE** I encoded the search query and added between the query tags with the token element as described in a previous comment.  I do not get an error but get no results either.  Just a blank table...

```
<query>             ...sourcetype%....%22%20%22%3CbillingMethod%3ERULE%3C%2FbillingMethod%3E%22%20%22createMessage%20MsgSource%22%20%7C%20xmlkv%20%7C%20rex%20max_match%3D0%20%22%5C%3CpurchasedCostTripSegment%5C%3E%28%3FP%3Csegment%3E%5B%5E%5C%3C%5D%2B%29%22%20%7Ceval%20Segments%20%3D%20%20mvrange%281%2Cmvcount%28mvindex%28segment%2C%200%2C%202%29%29%2B1%2C1%29%20%7C%20rex%20max_match%3D0%20%22%5C%3Ccarrier%5C%3E%28%3FP%3CCarriers%3E%5B%5E%5C%3C%5D%2B%29%22%20%7C%20rex%20max_match%3D0%20%22%5C%3CbillingMethod%5C%3E%28%3FP%3CBillingMethod%3E%5B%5E%5C%3C%5D%2B%29%22%20%7C%20rex%20max_match%3D0%20%22%3CpurchasedCostTripSegment%3E%5B%5Cs%5CS%5D%2A%3F%3Corigin%3E%5Cs%2A%3Cns2%3AnumberCode%3E%28%3FP%3COrigin%3E%5Cd%2B%29%22%20%20%7C%20rex%20max_match%3D0%20%22%3CpurchasedCostTripSegment%3E%5B%5Cs%5CS%5D%2A%3F%3Cdestination%3E%5Cs%2A%3Cns2%3AnumberCode%3E%28%3FP%3CDestination%3E%5Cd%2B%29%22%20%7C%20rex%20max_match%3D0%20%22%3CpurchasedCostTripSegment%3E%5B%5Cs%5CS%5D%2A%3F%3CstopOff%3E%5Cs%2A%3Cns2%3AstopOffLocation%3E%5Cs%2A%3Cns2%3AnumberCode%3E%28%3FP%3CStopOffLocation%3E%5Cd%2B%29%22%20%7C%20eval%20Time%20%3D_time%20%7C%20convert%20timeformat%3D%22%25m-%25d-%25Y%20%25H%3A%25M%3A%25S%22%20ctime%28Time%29%20%7C%20table%20purchCostReference%2C%20eventType%2C%20Time%2C%20Segments%2C%20Carriers%2C%20BillingMethod%2C%20Origin%2C%20Destination%2C%20StopOffLocation%20%7C%20sort%20Time purchCostReference=$purchCostReferenceToken$
</query>
```

This is a screen shot of the results:
[image]

**UPDATE**
I removed the complexity of the search so that it only has the index, source and sourcetype that is the same as the report and a text field to limit the search. Below is the query string:

```
<query>index="indexname same as report" source="source name same as report" sourcetype="source type name same as report" "createMessage MsgSource"</query>
```

It returns a blank dashboard with no error as pictured above.

**UPDATE**
I recreated the dashboard using the report query and have the search returning all of the table results.  I have an input for the reference number as a text box.  The token name is: **purchCostReferenceToken**

I want to limit the table results based on this token. This is the query:

```
<form>
  <label>Thru Train Dashboard</label>
  <fieldset submitButton="false" autoRun="true">
    <input type="text" token="purchCostReferenceToken" searchWhenChanged="true">
      <label>Enter a TMS Reference Number to Filter Table</label>
      <default>*</default>
      <initialValue>*</initialValue>
    </input>
  </fieldset>
  <row>
    <panel>
      <title>Thru Train Data</title>
      <table>
        <search>
          <query>index=... "&lt;billingMethod&gt;RULE&lt;/billingMethod&gt;" "createMessage MsgSource" | xmlkv | rex max_match=0 "\&lt;purchasedCostTripSegment\&gt;(?P&lt;segment&gt;[^\&lt;]+)" |eval Segments =  mvrange(1,mvcount(mvindex(segment, 0, 2))+1,1) | rex max_match=0 "\&lt;carrier\&gt;(?P&lt;Carriers&gt;[^\&lt;]+)" | rex max_match=0 "\&lt;billingMethod\&gt;(?P&lt;BillingMethod&gt;[^\&lt;]+)" | rex max_match=0 "&lt;purchasedCostTripSegment&gt;[\s\S]*?&lt;origin&gt;\s*&lt;ns2:numberCode&gt;(?P&lt;Origin&gt;\d+)"  | rex max_match=0 "&lt;purchasedCostTripSegment&gt;[\s\S]*?&lt;destination&gt;\s*&lt;ns2:numberCode&gt;(?P&lt;Destination&gt;\d+)" | rex max_match=0 "&lt;purchasedCostTripSegment&gt;[\s\S]*?&lt;stopOff&gt;\s*&lt;ns2:stopOffLocation&gt;\s*&lt;ns2:numberCode&gt;(?P&lt;StopOffLocation&gt;\d+)" | eval Time =_time | convert timeformat="%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S" ctime(Time) | table purchCostReference, eventType, Time, Segments, Carriers, BillingMethod, Origin, Destination, StopOffLocation | sort Time</query>
          <earliest>-30d@d</earliest>
          <latest>now</latest>
        </search>
        <option name="drilldown">none</option>
      </table>
    </panel>
  </row>
</form>
```

Where do I add the token to limit the search?
I tried adding this to the end of the query and all results were returned:

```
purchCostReference=$purchCostReferenceToken$
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send parameters to a Report. https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.4/Viz/PanelreferenceforSimplifiedXML#search

You will need to use an inline search, something like the following. You will need to include your search and filter it appropraitely with the token `$purchaseCoseReferenceToken`

```
<form>
  <label>Thru Train Dashboard</label>
  <fieldset submitButton="false" autoRun="true">
    <input type="text" token="purchCostReferenceToken" searchWhenChanged="true">
      <label>TMS Reference Number</label>
      <default>*</default>
      <initialValue>*</initialValue>
    </input>
  </fieldset>
  <row>
    <panel>
      <title>Thru Train XML DATA</title>
      <table>
        <search>
            <query>
            sourcetype=blah somefield="$purchCostReferenceToken$"
            </query>
        </search>
        <option name="drilldown">row</option>
        <option name="rowNumbers">true</option>
      </table>
    </panel>
  </row>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried removing the report reference and add the search string that creates the table but it can't compile the search.  **Invalid character in tag name** I updated the question above with what I did.

Comment: Yes, you need to urlencode your search query, copy and paste it in https://www.urlencoder.org/ for example.

Comment: Ok.  I did that and got the encoded query.  I added the encoded query between the **query** tags then added **purchCostReference=$purchCostReferenceToken$.  I did not get an error but did not get any results also. I added the query to the original post